# How to install Java in EC2 using userdata

Tags: java, amazon-ec2

I have to install Java in my EC2 using user data I am giving below command in my user data while launching instance but its not working as expected.

#!bin/bash

yum update -y

yum install java -y

If I give above command manually in my EC2 its getting installed properly. But while giving the same in User-Data its not getting installed.

Answer (score 1):

I created EC2 using Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 to install Java looks like we have to use below command.

yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk -y